# make better code in laravel many to many relation

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-8, relationship

hi i wrote this code and it works just fine but i think its not the best way to do it!

i want to get all the jobs for 1 company.

each company can have many addresses and each address can have many jobs

here is my code:

```
 $company = Company::find($id)->with('addresses.jobDetails.job')->first();
    $jobs = [];
    foreach ($company->addresses as $address) {
        foreach ($address->jobDetails as $detail) {
            array_push($jobs, [
                'id' => $detail->job->id,
                'title' => $detail->job->title,
                'country' => $detail->job->country,
                'city' => $detail->job->city,
                'type' => $detail->job->type,
                'work_types' => JobType::where('job_id',$detail->job->id)->pluck('title'),
                'income' => $detail->income,
            ]);
        }
    }
    return $jobs;
```

can anyone help me to change this to better code please

thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please share how your models are related? I mean relationships and DB structure. You probably can avoid all that messy code with just 1 eloquent query by starting from `Job` and using `whereHas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the opposite and start with JobDetails

```
$jobDetails = JobDetail::whereHas('address.company', function($companyQuery) use($id) {
    $companyQuery->where('id', $id);
})->whereHas('jobs', function($jobQuery) {
    $jobQuery->where('is_active', 1);
})->with('jobs')->get();

foreach ($jobDetails as $detail) {
    array_push($jobs, [
        'id' => $detail->job->id,
        'title' => $detail->job->title,
        'country' => $detail->job->country,
        'city' => $detail->job->city,
        'type' => $detail->job->type,
        'work_types' => JobType::where('job_id',$detail->job->id)->pluck('title'),
        'income' => $detail->income,
    ]);
}

return $jobs;
```

**EDIT:**

In your query

```
Company::find($id)->with('addresses.jobDetails.job')->first();
```

You run 4 queries with eager loading. one for each model. You can check in the result that you got that all the data is present in the variable `$company`.

The example I gave you it runs only two queries, the first one (job_details) will use joins to filter the Job results by the `id` of the companies table (you can make it faster by using the field `company_id` in the addresses table)
The second one is for the jobs relation using eager loading.

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you explain how this is better?

Comment: @miladhedayatpoor hope that is enough explanations. you could have run them both in your installation to check which was faster.